# How do I acces a variables outside the map function in js puppeteer

Tags: javascript, list, function, mapping, puppeteer

Ok so I am trying to use map functions to get multiple elements from a [Website](https://www.alibaba.com/Products) (with puppeteer) and those elements have multiple children and their children have multiple children and so on. So I need to store those items in a way right?

And I can't access keyData1 and keyData2 AND keyData3 at the same time, I have to access them in a way that I don't know how. I tried to push them in a list but I remembered that I still don't know how to access it from outside of the function, anyways if anyone has a solution please tell me i really need to learn this map thing I am a beginner btw and here is the code

```
const test = await page.evaluate(() => {

    var list= [];

    [...document.querySelectorAll('.item.util-clearfix')].map(item =>{

       keyData1 = item.querySelector('h3').innerText;
       list.push(keyData1);

      [...item.querySelectorAll('.sub-item')].map(item =>{

         keyData2 = item.querySelector('h4').innerText;
         list.push(keyData2);

        [...item.querySelectorAll('li')].map(item=>{

          var keyData3 = item.innerText;
          list.push(keyData3);

          console.log(list);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: do you mean to say return list back to main program?

Comment: Yeah well, that'll work too i just wanna be able to interact with all the items inside that list as a whole you know, like i have to unite them, preferably into a list

Comment: What data are you trying to get or action are you trying to perform, exactly? What's wrong with the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need some hierarchical tree of data: an object of objects of objects as branches with arrays of leaves (final elements). Try this, maybe this is what you need:

```js
const test = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const tree = {};

  for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.item.util-clearfix')) {
    const keyData1 = item.querySelector('h3').innerText;
    tree[keyData1] = {};

    for (const subItem of item.querySelectorAll('.sub-item')) {
      const keyData2 = subItem.querySelector('h4').innerText;
      tree[keyData1][keyData2] = [];

      for (const li of subItem.querySelectorAll('li')) {
        const keyData3 = li.innerText;
        tree[keyData1][keyData2].push(keyData3);
      }
    }
  }

  return tree;
});

console.log(test);
// or maybe:
// console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, '  '));
```

Then you can iterate over the branches with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and iterate over the leaves with array methods.